# When I use multiple monitor and each monitor has each resolution, my picturebox is not working

Tags: c#, .net, directshow

I made a video player with directshow, and I used picturebox as IVideoWindow like below.

```
        pVideoWindow.put_Owner(pictureboxhdl.Handle);
        pVideoWindow.put_WindowStyle(WindowStyle.Child | WindowStyle.ClipSiblings);
        Rectangle rect = pictureboxhdl.ClientRectangle;
        pVideoWindow.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);
```

However when i move the Form to other monitor(which has different resolution), my Directshow does not update(refresh) image on Picturebox.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to specify monitor [`IVMRMonitorConfig::SetMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms787102) for your video renderer since video delivery might be using resources different from those used by application UI in general.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23844244/868014